# Решить задачку на Си используя стандартную библиотеку и string,h

Tags: c

Ввести строку символов-разделителей между словами, а затем строку текста, состоящую из слов и символов-разделителей, находящихся в произвольном количестве до и после слов. Подсчитать количество слов, начинающихся с гласной буквы. Вывести эти слова в порядке неубывания длины

Я хочу перекинуть нужные слова в новый массив и сравнивать элементы этого массива но почему то не перекидывается

```
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            a[j] += str[i];
        if ((str[i]!=' ')&&(str[i-1]==' '))
            j++;
    }
```

эта часть не работает

Comment: `a[j] += str[i];` - ??

Comment: с чаром так нельзя?

Comment: Не нужен новый массив. Слово это пара разделитель+гласная. Только первое слово не такое так как может идти от начала строки. Собственно количество таких пар равно количеству искомых слов.

Comment: В задании вам подсказывают, для разбиения строки (выделения слов) используйте [strtok](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) или [strsep](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep) или [strspn/strcspn](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) / Полный список функций из string.h см. [man 3 string](https://linux.die.net/man/3/string)